# floated child div width not to affect the parent width

Tags: html, css

I have a child div which is affecting the width of the parent div.

I want the child div should not affect the width of the parent div.

For that i have used postion:absolute. But that makes the page itself grow out.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HDg5A/1/)

I want the child div should not grow out of the page and at the same time it should not grow the width of the parent

which happens [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HDg5A/2/) if i remove the position:absolute;

The html -

```
<div class="htext">
Me
<div id="m_two">This is a test</div>
</div>
```

The css -

```
.htext {
float:right;
background-color:#ccccff;
}
#m_two {
float:left;
width:200px;
position:absolute;
}
```

Regards

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/HDg5A/3/

Comment: nope the child div should be below but it should affect the width of the parent. like - http://jsfiddle.net/HDg5A/1/ but this grows out of the page.

Comment: So, just set right: 0; http://jsfiddle.net/HDg5A/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your CSS like below.

```
.htext {
float:right;
background-color:#ccccff;
}
#m_two {
width:200px;
position:absolute;
right:0;
float:left;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HDg5A/8/)

Comment: why do you use the position:relative in the parent. It can be done without.

Comment: you are right. I try with different things in fiddle, forget to remove that style. Now I updated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HDg5A/9/)

Well, here one thing can help you which is `display:inline-block`.

CSS WILL BE FOLLOWING:

```
.htext {
    display:inline-block;   
    background-color:#ccccff;
    position:relative;
}
#m_two {
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    position:absolute;
    background:#F00;
}
```